# passing props to the same parent with different children in vue router

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

I have this Footer component:

```
<template>
  <v-footer >    
    <span>{{ new Date().toLocaleTimeString() }}</span>       
      <span>Need help?</span>
        <a :href="`mailto:${email}`">{{ email }}</a>
  </v-footer>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
const props = defineProps({
  email: { required: true, type: String },
});

</script>
```

and have this MainApp component:

```
<template>
    // ...
    <custom-footer :email="email"/>
    //...
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import ...

const props = defineProps({
  email: { required: true, type: String, default: "support@gmail.com" },
});

</script>
```

and I have my routes configured this way, having three routes addressing me to three components:

index.ts

```
import RouteNames from '../route-names';
import type { RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router';

const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'MainApp',
    component: () => import('@/MainApp.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: 'one',
        name: RouteNames.ONE,
        component: () => import('/One.vue'),
      },
      {
        path: 'two',
        name: RouteNames.TWO,
        component: () => import('Two.vue'),
      },
      {
        path: 'three',
        name: RouteNames.THREE,
        component: () => import('@/Three.vue'),
      },     
    ],
  },
];

export default routes;
```

but I want to pass different email props two my footer, because in some routes I want in footer `email:"email1@gmail.com"` and on the rest `email:"email2@gmail.com"`, so I did this:

index1.ts

```
//this email value for one and two routes

const routes1: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'MainApp',
    props: {email:"email1@gmail.com"},
    component: () => import('@/MainApp.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: 'one',
        name: RouteNames.ONE,
        component: () => import('/One.vue'),
      },
      {
        path: 'two',
        name: RouteNames.TWO,
        component: () => import('Two.vue'),
      },    
    ],
  },
];

export default routes1;
```

index2.ts

```
//this email value for three route

const routes2: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'MainApp',
    props: {email:"email2@gmail.com"},
    component: () => import('@/MainApp.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: 'three',
        name: RouteNames.THREE,
        component: () => import('@/Three.vue'),
      },     
    ],
  },
];

export default routes2;
```

everything ok, without errors here, so on my router/index.ts:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import routes1 from './routes/index1';
import routes2 from './routes/index2';
import beforeEachGuards from './guards/index';

const combinedRoutes = [...routes1,...routes2];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory('/next/'),
  routes: combinedRoutes,
});

beforeEachGuards.forEach(guard => {
  router.beforeEach(guard)
});

export default router;
```

then in main.ts:

```
const vue = createApp(App);


vue.use(router);


router.isReady().then(() => {
  vue.mount('#app');
});
```

But it is not working.

What would be a better approach than this?

********** EDIT *************************

tryin to find another way I am using the beforeEnter hook as fallows:

```
{
    path: '/',
    name: 'MainApp',
    component: () => import('@MainApp.vue'),
    props:true,
    beforeEnter(to,from,next){
      let email: string;
      switch (to.name){
        case RouteNames.ONE:
          email="supportOne@gmail.com";
          break;
        default:
          email="supportThree@gmail.com";
      }
      next((vm:any) => {
        vm.$props.email = email;
      });
    },
    children: [ //..
```

but now in spite of being close this is not working:

```
next((vm:any) => {
   vm.$props.email = email;
});
```

Comment: Please consider to create a *Minimal, Reproducible Example* using [Codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/) or some other service to get help faster. Here is FAQ on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I am trying to use the beforeEnter hook, almost there but now I have another problem. will update the code in the main question